# AWS CodeDeploy Jenkins Plugin with Jenkins Pileline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, aws-code-deploy

Is it possible to use AWSCodeDeployPublisher as step in Jenkins Pipeline? I know there is a pull request with support https://github.com/awslabs/aws-codedeploy-plugin/pull/60 but maybe there is a workaround for unsupported plugins like this one to use them as step in Jenkinsfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like support has been added in [this PR](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-codedeploy-plugin/pull/72).